# Create a time with time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to this please any help would be great! I am creating a date warehouse for a credit card company for school and in this table it is asking for the table TRANSACTION to having the following Date, Time, Amount, and Authorization Code. Here is what I have so far for just this table

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    trans_date DATE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    trans_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    trans_amount DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    auth_code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('1984-12-15', '2000-03-15 11:15:23', 200.00, 'IH1546');
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('2001-01-22', '2014-05-15 12:45:20', 300.00, 'IH2563');
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('1998-10-30', '2017-01-14 13:11:45', 400.00, 'IH4457');
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('2003-02-11', '2007-10-28 09:05:56', 500.00, 'IH8977');
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('1985-12-23', '2009-06-29 16:37:03', 600.00, 'IH9975');

SELECT *
FROM transactions;
```

The problem I am encountering is

> Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

Can anyone help me or walk me through what I need to do for time, I have been searching online for two days and not really finding anything that comes close to what I need. Each record should all have different times in them?

Comment: Your table doesn't have a `timestamp` column, so it is unclear where this could be coming from.  Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: I know this might sound stupid so please bear with me but what is a trigger

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use a date as a primary key? You're only allowing one transaction per day?

Comment: I actually suspect you may have an old version of `transactions` in your db. Try `drop table transactions` and then recreate it with your `create` statement above.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think so since each of the records  that is listed and from unique individuals

Comment: just a question would be helpful to list the whole database so you all can see?

Comment: `Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Line 18` Your example has 15 lines.

Comment: you probably has wrongly created the `trans_time` column as timestamp

Comment: @Squirrel Ok I am unsure how to fix

Comment: When I run your posted script I do not get the error (which is no suprise). You need to post the script that generates the error. It's definitely not that one because there is no line 18 in it, and there is no column with a timestamp datatype

Comment: First step is: post the script that generates the error - the one you've posted does not generate that error

Comment: Oh and don't worry no one thinks any questions are silly - ask away! the challenge is just explaining your issue

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. There are four total tables in this database so far and this is the third table. I am having issues posting the whole thing for everyone to see. But I Just execute this again and I get the same error message.                                                                                                  Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

Comment: Double click the error message and it will take you to the line that threw it. What does that line say?

Comment: INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('1984-12-15', '2000-03-15 11:15:23', 200.00, 'IH1546'); @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Can you press View / Object Explorer, connect to your database server, open the tree out and find your _transactions_ table in the tables folder. Open that out and check the columns. Do you see any columns with `timestamp` written against them? if not, then again, under your table, open out the `Triggers` folder and see if there any triggers. Make extra sure you are looking at the correct table in the correct database.

Comment: To clarify: a column with datatype _timestamp_ is not what you want to record a date with a time. For that you want a datatype `datetime`. Your script above uses `datetime`, not `timestamp` so let us work out whats going on here.

Comment: I figure I need this code SELECT convert(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100). Because this table needs date, time, amount, and authorization code. But with this code above I am unsure how to write this table. As far as CREATE TABLE  and then the records such as INSERT INTO with the code above. Do you have an example? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: The table you have posted is perfect for the purpose but the error makes no sense. What did your investigations come up with. Is there a time stamp column?

Comment: yes there is, and when I go to change it from TIMESTAMP to datetime  it tells me the changes that I have made can't be saved, the table needs to be dropped and re-created

Comment: ok say I deleted everything and went back in and redid the entire code and everything works great. Thank you Nick I would never have thought to open that up and look at the columns @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Great to hear you made some progress.